# Invalid use of group function with no aggregate function in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Getting an error that I'm not grouping properly or what I am grouping isnt allowed but I searched around a bit and didn't see a case like this. All the other posts that had this error had an aggregate function in the where clause. Nothing changes unless I completely remove the grouping. Using an actual date in the where clause rather than

```
>= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

doesnt change the result.

Im looking for an support agent's name, a label that was applied to a case that they were on, the average rating for that agent on that label, and the count of how many tickets they worked on with that label applied.

This is the query I'm running:

```
select a.public_name, 'settings', format(avg(r.rating),2) as 'average', 
count(label_name), pk_case_id
from bi.support_agents_list a 
    join bi.support_ratings_agents sra 
    on a.desk_id = sra.agent_desk_id
    join bi.support_ratings r 
    on sra.response_id = r.response_id
    and r.survey_id = sra.survey_id
    join bizdw.support_labels_assigned_v2 l
    on l.fk_case_id = r.pk_case_id
where r.date_submitted >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
and a.start_date < '2014-01-22'
and a.end_date is null
and lower(l.label_name) in ('settings',
'settings-contributor'
'settings-socialaccount')
group by a.public_name, 'settings', format(avg(r.rating),2), pk_case_id
order by a.public_name, format(avg(r.rating),2), label_name desc
```

Comment: group by count(label_name) ???

Comment: That wasnt supposed to be in there, I was trying a few things when I copy/pasted. I replaced format(avg(r.rating),2) with 'average' and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is your `group by` clause:

```
group by a.public_name, 'settings', format(avg(r.rating),2), pk_case_id
```

The constant `'settings'` is unnecessary (allowed but it doesn't do anything).  The `format(avg(r.rating),2)` is causing the error.  The clause can simply be:

```
group by a.public_name, pk_case_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing group by based on format(avg(r.rating),2) along with other columns even avg(r.rating) itself will be calculated based on either for whole table or based on group by, so you can't include a computed column in group by, which is not logical correct.

If it is your requirement then first you have to get avg(rating) in derived query based on productname and other required columns then you can join this derived table with your main table and you can include avg(rating) column also in group by clause along with other columns like productnames etc.